# How can I import a Filemaker database into EE?

Tags: database, import

I have a client who has their organization's membership info in a Filemaker database. Can anyone provide guidance as to how I can bring that database into EE? Ideally, I'd like to move the membership database functions out of Filemaker entirely and into EE.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[DataGrab](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab) and [Solspace Importer](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/importer/) add-ons can both import various types of data into EE, such as CSV, XML, etc that can be exported from FileMaker.

I would look at both of these add-ons and work out which one is best suited to your needs based on the complexity of your source data.